# Changing method behaviour depending on subtype of 2 input parameters

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to create a card game with a clean class design.
I would like to compare 2 cards and return the one with the highest "value".

I have an abstract card class and 2 classes inherited from it :

```
    public abstract class Card {
      ...
      //common method
      public int getCardValue() { return this.cardValue; }
      //comparison methods
      public abstract Card compare(ColoredCard card);
      public abstract Card compare(TrumpCard card);
    }

    public class ColoredCard extends Card {
      //specific attribute
      private Color cardColor;
      ...
      //specific method
      public Color getColor() { return this.cardColor; }

      public Card compare(ColoredCard card) {
        if(this.getColor() == card.getColor())
          return this.getCardValue() > card.getCardValue() ? this : card;
        return this;
      }

      public Card compare(TrumpCard card) {
        return card;
      }
    }

    public class TrumpCard extends Card {
      ...
      public Card compare(ColoredCard card) {
        return this;
      }

      public Card compare(TrumpCard card) {
        return this.getCardValue() > card.getCardValue() ? this : card;
      }
    }
```

But it still throw an error whenever I try :

```
Card c = new ColoredCard(5);
Card c2 = new TrumpCard(1);
c.compareTo(c2); //error method compareTo not applicable to type of argument "Card"
```

I NEED to access whole subclass interface to do each of my comparison but also keep the comparison call "generic" (through Card superclass).

I would like to avoid to use `instanceOf` instruction or reflection if possible.

Thank you,

Comment: Shouldn't `compare` simply accept two `Card`s?

Comment: No, because for each compare I need to access specifics methods of my subclasses.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with how you designed your classes. It would help to see how the relevant parts are implemented and how you want to compare them. In other words the `compare` method should not have to know how to compare two cards based on their type. It should be the `Card` type that exposes a `compareTo` method and it should be able to handle different types of card by itself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your feedback ! I have put some additional information about my classes design into my original post. I will try your design suggestion and keep this thread updated !

Comment: I made what you recommended. It seems that I just had to implement each "compare(CardSubtype card)" method within each of my card subclass !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way which work using Visitor pattern :

```
public interface ICardVisitor {
    public Card visit(TrumpCard card);
    public Card visit(ColoredCard card);
    public void setSecondCard(ColoredCard card);
    public void setSecondCard(TrumpCard card);
}

public class ComparisonVisitor implements ICardVisitor {
    private TrumpCard trumpCard;
    private ColoredCard coloredCard;
    ...
    //contains comparison logic & instances of card subtypes
}
```

I also had to add an extra function (in addition to the classic accept(Visitor v) method) to my abstract Card class :

```
public abstract void setThisCardAsParameter(ICardVisitor v);
```

inside the concrete Card implementations :

```
public Card accept(ICardVisitor visitor) {
    return visitor.visit(this);
}

public void setThisCardAsParameter(ICardVisitor v) {
    v.setSecondCard(this);
}
```

This way the comparison class know each subtype for each card so he has access to all specific methods of a given child class.
The call is looking like this :

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    ICardVisitor cmp = new ComparisonVisitor();
    Card c = new TrumpCard(1);
    Card c2 = new ColoredCard(CardTypes.SPADES,1);
    ICardVisitor cmp = new ComparisonVisitor();
    c.setThisCardAsParameter(cmp);
    Card winningCard = c2.accept(cmp);
}
```

If that design is bad or can be improved, please let me know it !

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, I would define an abstract method on the base class that lets the subclasses provide their absolute value. Then you can make the base class `Comparable` and implement a `compareTo()` method that uses this value. The value doesn't even need to be revealed publicly.

```
public static abstract class Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.value(), other.value());
    }

    protected abstract int value();
}

public static class ColoredCard extends Card {

    @Override
    protected int value() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public static class TrumpCard extends Card {

    @Override
    protected int value() {
        return 10;
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new TrumpCard().compareTo(new ColoredCard()));
    System.out.println(new ColoredCard().compareTo(new TrumpCard()));
}
```

Prints:

> 1
>   
> -1

If that's no good, then you will need to use `instanceof` or something like the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or rethink the design.

For example, you could redesign so that rather than having a separate class for each card, you hold the kind of card as a field (perhaps using an enum). Then when you compare two cards you can compare the kinds of the two cards, won't need to use `instanceof` and can incorporate whatever logic you like.

E.g.

```
public static enum Kind {
    COLORED,
    TRUMP;
}

public static class Card {
    private final Kind kind;

    public Card(Kind kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public Kind kind() {
        return kind;
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Card trumpCard = new Card(Kind.TRUMP);
    Card coloredCard = new Card(Kind.COLORED);

    int i = compare(trumpCard, coloredCard);
}

public static int compare(Card card, Card other) {
    if (card.kind().equals(other.kind())) {                
        return 0;
    }
    if (card.kind().equals(Kind.TRUMP)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would not work. I need to compare the cards using some specific subclass method in each case - I can't simply compare values

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to have an elegant solution which automatically dispatch to a given comparison method depending on the 2 cards subtypes ? The solution with "Kind" enum is easy to implement and should work but I do not find it good : it is a duplicated information because each subclass will ALWAYS have a different "Kind" (equivalence relation)

Comment: There is a way to dispatch without `instanceof`, as I mentioned, you can use the Visitor pattern to dispatch to a Visitor with overloaded methods (one per card type). But I've never found it particularly elegant.